# How do I remove spiritual chametz along with the physical?

Tags: passover, middos-character-traits, mussar-ethics

I've heard the idea many times that as we approach Pesach we should be worried not only about the physical chametz in our houses but also the spiritual chametz (hubris etc) that we carry in our souls.  I realize that the best approach to addressing this is probably to engage in a deep study of middot, but are there smaller, incremental things one can do to at least start down the path?  Where does one start -- what are the right sources to study or prayers/practices to take on?

Comment: While writing this question I intended to tag it chametz, but on seeing the tag wiki I reconsidered.

Comment: tag [tag:how-to] ?

Comment: @Shokhet seems plausible.  Go for it.

Answer (score 5):

Oddly enough, the means to "remove Chametz" from our souls is very nicely laid out in the Chasidic practices of the 49 days of Sefirat Haomer.  If you search the internet, you will find numerous 49 step programs, that a person can do, each day to make themselves a better person and have a better relationship with Gd, thus removing the "Chametz".

Now that you ask the question, I find it odd that nobody has such programs for the 15 days before Pesach. Or even 30 days from Purim to Pesach.

However, I would argue that Purim and it's meanings is a good place to start.  After all, Yom Kipurim, is "like Purim", so Purim itself must be a very cleansing holiday.  Perhaps that is why there is no 30 day program from Purim to Pesach, but instead the "program" is done during Sefirat HaOmer.

Answer (score 4):

It surely can only do good to learn a little mussar each day. I find the first perek of Mesilas Yeshorim most beautiful and it repays deep thought.